# Is there a way to import an non-existence module without getting a error?

Tags: python, module

I know this sounds meta but, I'm trying to test out a module error I made myself and trying to make the python interpreter skip the module if it's not found.

Code I've tried:

```
if ModuleNotFoundError is blah:
print("blah blah blah")
while True:
    blah = input("Continue? (y or n)")
    if blah == "y":
        break
    if blah == "n":
        sys.exit("Game exited")
    else:
        pass
```

There's an option to skip and continue if it's not found. However when I try to run the script this happens in the windows powershell
input:

```
 & C:/Users/sayne/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe "c:/Users/sayne/Documents/ireallylovecoding/python and practice/Interrogation/main.py"
```

output:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blah'
```

Can anyone help me? (P.S Blah is a python file in the same directory as my main.py file.)

Comment: Use try except instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
try:
    import blah
    print('Do whatever you want to do if the module does import.')
except ImportError:
    print('Do whatever you want to do if the module does not import.')
```